# Retrieving Sets in a HDF5 file in Julia

Tags: julia, hdf5

There seems to be an issue between JLD, HDF5 and JLD2 formats for storing complex data in Julia. Until recently, JLD seemed to work pretty well, and it was suppossed to be HDF5-compatible. I have a data set that includes some data with data type Set. Saving and retrieving it on JLD format was straightforward. But now JLD is depprecated as of Julia 1.0.0, and JLD2 is "the new way to do it", but it explicitly says in the page that is not backwards compatible or that is safe ("  If your tolerance for data loss is low, JLD may be a better choice at this time"). Okey, but JLD does not compule on Julia 1.0.0. So I cannot use it.
HDF5 seems to open the JLD adecuately, and to be able to retrieve arrays well. But not the sets. When I try to retrieve a Set I get this:

```
HDF5.HDF5Compound{1}((UInt8[0x68, 0x59, 0x46, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],), ("dict_",), (HDF5.HDF5ReferenceObj,))
```

I do not know what kind of object this is, or how to interpret it. The original data was a set cointaing two integer arrays as elements. I tried to read it by indices but that cannot be made, and it says something akin to "dict", but it has no names on it.

I may be able to translate all data to JLD or to a plain HDF5 with a Julia 0.6.2  Script, but maybe I can learn to do it right with hdf5 + Julia 1.0.0